# Implicit/Explicit conversion between two lists/IEnumerable in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, implicit-conversion, explicit-conversion

Can I make Implicit/Explicit conversion between two lists i.e.

```
List<Person> person = new List<Human>();
```

Comment: No, I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: Not exactly clear if you are asking if you can add implicit/explicit conversion operators to existing type (List) or trying to do conversion between list of derived classes to list of base classes... But good thing we already have answers to both. If you are asking something else - [edit] question to clarify.

Comment: Try it with a type that has implicit conversion already, and you'll see that you can't: `List<double> foo = new List<int>();`

Comment: You can assign a list of humans to a list of persons with an explicit cast in a select statement, though `List<Person> people = humans.Select(h => (Person)h).ToList();` (assuming such a cast is valid).